# mysql print name and sid of students enrolled in most classes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

Tables:

- student(sid, sname, sex, age, year, gpa)
- dept(dname, numphds)
- prof(pname, dname)
- course(cno, cname, dname)
- major(dname, sid)
- section(dname, cno, sectno, pname)
- enroll(sid, grade, dname, cno, sectno)

Question:
5.  Print the `name`(s) and `sid`(s) of the `student`(s) enrolled in the most classes.

```
select s.sname, s.sid, count(*) 
from student s, enroll e 
where s.sid = e.sid 
having count(*) = (select max(counted) 
                   from (
                        select count(*) as counted 
                        from student s, enroll e 
                        where s.sid = e.sid 
                        group by s.sname
                        ) as counts
                   ) 
group by sname;
```

I keep getting different errors. the inner loops give me the max in the database when run independently but once I put it together it has syntax errors and group by errors

EDIT: ADDITIONAL QUESTIONS: 
10.Print the age difference between the oldest and youngest Computer Sciences major(s).

11. For each department that has one or more majors with a GPA under 1.0, print the name of the department and the average GPA of its majors.
12. Print the ids, names, and GPAs of the students who are currently taking all of the Civil Engineering courses.

Been stuck on these for a while. Any help would be appreciated.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
student
sid     sname           sex     age     year    gpa
1       Jacobs, T.      m       29      5       3.60
2       Pierson, E.     m       32      5       3.50
3       Zeene, Ben N.   m       21      5       3.90

dept
dname                   numphds
Chemical Engineering    32
Civil Engineering       88
Computer Sciences       47

prof
pname        dname
Brian, C.    Computer Sciences
Brown, S.    Civil Engineering
Bucket, T.   Sanitary Engineering

course
cno          cname                  dname
302          Intro to Programming   Computer Sciences
310          Thermodynamics         Chemical Engineering
310          Intro to Garbage       Sanitary Engineering

major
dname                   sid
Chemical Engineering    25
Chemical Engineering    26
Chemical Engineering    27

section
dname                   cno     sectno  pname
Chemical Engineering    310     1       Edison, L.
Civil Engineering       365     1       Randolph, B.
Civil Engineering       375     1       Brown, S.

enroll
sid     grade   dname                   cno     sectno
1       3.00    Chemical Engineering    310     1
2       3.00    Computer Sciences       302     1
3       3.50    Civil Engineering       375     1
```

Comment: You say you get errors. If you want help, you should specify your errors. Also, what results do you get for each of the subquery? How much of the query do you have to remove to make things work? How does it fail when you add one thing back?

Comment: This works and gives me the max: select max(counted) from (select count(*) as counted from student s, enroll e where s.sid = e.sid group by s.sname) as counts. Once I add the outer query I get error 1064 syntax error.

Comment: What is the are minimum you have to add to that to make it fail?

Comment: The outer query as I stated previously: "select s.sname, s.sid, count(*) from student s, enroll e where s.sid = e.sid having count(*) = ........... group by sname;"

Comment: Other option would be:
SELECT s.sname, e.sid, e.count FROM student s, (Select sid, count(sid) as count FROM enroll Group by sid Order by count DESC LIMIT 1) as e where s.sid = e.sid

Comment: @AdamOcsvari that didn't work. Its supposed to give me the student(s) enrolled in most courses, that just gives me one student who is enrolled in one course, even when I add group by still the same.

Comment: SELECT s.sname, e.sid, e.count FROM student s, (Select sid, count(sid) as count FROM enroll Group by sid) as e Where e.count = max(e.count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the first one:

10. Print the age difference between the oldest and youngest Computer Sciences major(s).

    select((select max(s.age) from student s, major m where s.sid = m.sid and m.dname = 'Computer Sciences') - (select min(s1.age) from student s1, major m1 where s1.sid=m1.sid and m1.dname = 'Computer Sciences')) as Difference;

Now just need the other 2 if anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

**having** should be placed after **group by**：

```
select Artists_id,count(*)
from dbo.Artits a,Author b
where a.Artists_id=b.au_id
group by Artists_id  --  put here
having count(*) = 
( 
    select max(counted) 
    from 
    (
        select COUNT(*) as counted  from dbo.Artits a,Author b
        where a.Artists_id=b.au_id
        group by Artists_id
    ) as counts
)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT sname,sid 
FROM student
WHERE sid IN (
    SELECT sid FROM enroll GROUP BY sid HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enroll GROUP BY sid
    )
)